# Name in sys.availability_groups_cluster returns double character length

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, system-tables

'select name, len(name) as length from sys.availability_groups_cluster'

Returns some double values:

| name | length |
| --- | --- |
| AG_QBUS_MFG01 | 13 |
| AG_QBUS003 | 20 |
| TEST_ONLY | 18 |

Comment: `LEN` returns the number of characters, `DATALENGTH` returns the number of bytes.  And sys.objects doesn't do this: `select name, len(name) from sys.objects`.  Are there trailing spaces?  try `select concat('[',name,']') name, len(name)`

Answer (score 2):

An update was included in [SQL Server 2022 CU10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2022/cumulativeupdate10#2714261) that might address this issue:

> Fixes unexpected characters that you encounter in the name column of the `sys.availability_groups_cluster` dynamic management view (DMV) when you use the read-scale availability group.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is driven by cluster(s) set up. If I get the value from `sys.availability_groups` instead of `sys.availability_groups_cluster` it returns the results as expected.